# Дополнительная сортировка коллекции

Tags: java

Фильтрую список объектов по полю. Не могу понять как сделать дополнительную фильтрацию например последние 10 записей.

```
getReadings().stream().filter(r -> r.getCity().equals(city)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы, например, можете написать кастомный colletor. Типа такого:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> lastN(int n) {
    return Collector.<T, Deque<T>, List<T>>of(ArrayDeque::new, (acc, t) -> {
        if (acc.size() == n)
            acc.pollFirst();
        acc.add(t);
    }, (acc1, acc2) -> {
        while (acc2.size() < n && !acc1.isEmpty()) {
            acc2.addFirst(acc1.pollLast());
        }
        return acc2;
    }, ArrayList<T>::new);
}
```

И дальше его использовать примерно так:

```
getReadings().stream().filter(r -> r.getCity().equals(city)).collect(lastN(10));
```

---

<sub>По мотивам [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477722/6104996)</sub>